# Problem in using Boost Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, boost-test

I want to start to use Boost Test library to create tests for my application.

Following the tutorial that I've found at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/test/doc/html/tutorials/new-year-resolution.html I've started my test class.

So, I've created a class for my test, and the simple .cpp is this one

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyClass test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "myclasstest.h"

MyClassTest::MyClassTest()
{

}

/**
 * Test the class.
 */
bool MyClassTest::testClass()
{
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(empty_test)
    {
        MyClass xTest;
        BOOST_CHECK(xTest.isEmpty());
    }

return true;
}
```

Ok, I know that I must do something more intelligent than return true, but it' not the problem. The problem is that it does not compile.
I think that library is corrected loaded, because If I compile only with first two rows I've no error, as explained in the tutorial page.

If I try to compile it, I obtain this error output from GCC:

```
myclasstest.cpp: In member function ‘bool MyClassTest::testClass()’:
myclasstest.cpp:16:5: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
myclasstest.cpp:16:1: error: ‘empty_test_invoker’ was not declared in this scope
myclasstest.cpp:16:5: error: template argument for ‘template<class T> struct  boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_tc_exp_fail’ uses local type ‘MyClassTest::testClass()::empty_test_id’
myclasstest.cpp:16:5: error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class T> struct boost::unit_test::ut_detail::auto_tc_exp_fail’
myclasstest.cpp:17:5: error: a function-definition is not allowed here before ‘{’ token
myclasstest.cpp:23:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
myclasstest.cpp:23:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
```

I'm new to Boost, so I don't know what I must do. What I'm doing wrong? I think that I've done the same steps of tutorial, or not?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE should be places on a file scope. It cannot be places inside function implementation. You can use class method based test cases, but not with automatic registration (for the time being). Check the documentation for more details

Answer (score 0):

You should use BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE with not member functions. For example:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyClass test
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "MyClass.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( testMyClass )
{
   MyClass xTest;
   BOOST_CHECK(xTest.isEmpty());
}
```

Check [fixtures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/fixture.html) if you need a test context.